Should questions contain quotes if they refer to external sources?
In this particular case I am referring to Treating independent code as a function in IDA Pro (and I don't mean to make this a pillory at all!)
Original (full) answer as of this writing:

This is probably off-topic but it sounds like what you need is node
  groups.

On other SE sites I have often found moderators and other community members pointing out that external sources should be quoted with there most vital statements. This is what I did on Igor's answer, too. Likely reasoning behind this is that if the external link goes stale, the person trying to locate the new location of that information will have it more easy to find what is needed.
You could arguably take at least two sides:

this is redundant
essential parts have to be quoted to provide context

Which is it for this SE site?

We should follow the network wide policy on link only answers and not try a different approach as the reasoning behind this policy is rather solid (which you yourself have pointed out).
Quoting the relevant parts :

I think that links are fantastic, but they should never be the only
  piece of information in your answer.
When someone goes on StackOverflow, the question "answer" should
  actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the
  answer. You should provide context to all your links, otherwise the OP
  will have no idea what they are clicking into.


Yes, I think this is the right way to go. Answers should stand on their own, and links should be used to provide supporting citations or more in-depth information.

@AshRj: yep, totally agree. Thanks for pointing to the network-wide policy on that one and +1

I agree with this as well.
